Density matrix equations
I am studying a paper (http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0022-3727/48/14/145301) in which the Hamiltonian is:
$$H = \sum_{i}\epsilon_{i}\sigma_{ii} - \hbar\omega_{p}\hat{a}_{p}\hat{\sigma}^{\dagger}_{ba}e^{-\iota\Delta_{1}t} - g\hat{a}_{\beta}\hat{\sigma}^{\dagger}_{ac}e^{-\iota\Delta_{2}t} + h.c  .$$
where we have a three level quantum dot interacting with two fields.$ a_{p}$ is the probe field operator, $a_{\beta}$ is the spp field operator and $\sigma$ is the quantum dot operator. $\Delta_{1}$ and $\Delta_{2}$ are the detuning of fields from the corresponding transition frequencies of quantum dot. The two fields are resonant with the two transitions of Q. dot . In the paper, they are calculating density matrix elements using master equation. when they derive these equations, there are no field operators terms. I am giving few equations here:
$\frac{d \rho_{bb}}{dt} = 2\gamma_{b} \rho_{aa} -\iota \Omega_{p} \rho_{ba} + \iota\Omega_{p} \rho_{ab}\\$
$\frac{d \rho_{cc}}{dt} = 2\gamma_{c} \rho_{aa} -\iota\Xi \rho_{ca} + i\Xi\rho_{ac}\\$
$\frac{d \rho_{ab}}{dt} = -(\gamma_{b}+\gamma_{c}-i\delta_{ab})\rho_{ab} + i\Omega_{p}\rho_{cb}-i\Xi(\rho_{aa}-\rho_{bb})\\$
why? what kind of approximation or some other method they are using?

This site generally requires questions to be self-contained and clear. To make this question more self contained and clear, please include the actual equations referred to in this part: "when they derive these equations, there are no field operators terms. why?"

I have added some eqautions.
